# Retrofit 2: App Crashes When Reading JSON Without Internet

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I am trying to stop my app from crashing when trying to read json information using Gson and Retrofit2 when user has no internet connection. Any Ideas?

My code:

**Fragment**

```
class ManuFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: ManuFragmentVM

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        _binding = FragmentManuBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ManuFragmentVM::class.java)

        viewModel.apply {
            manufacturer.observe(requireActivity(), {loadRecyclerView(it)})
            setup()
        }
    }
```

**View Model**

```
class ManuFragmentVM : ViewModel() {

    val manufacturer = MutableLiveData<List<Manufacturers>>()

    fun setup() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            manufacturer.postValue(CarsRepository().getAllManufacturers())
        }
    }
```

**Interface**

```
interface ManufacturerApi {
    @GET("url.json")
    suspend fun fetchAllManufacturers(): List<Manufacturers>
}
```

**Repository**

```
class CarsRepository {

    private fun manufacturerRetrofit(): ManufacturerApi {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://website.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().create()))
            .build()
            .create(ManufacturerApi::class.java)
    }

    suspend fun getAllManufacturers(): List<Manufacturers> {
        return manufacturerRetrofit().fetchAllManufacturers()

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you only need to wrap your call in a try-catch:

```
fun setup() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            manufacturer.postValue(CarsRepository().getAllManufacturers())
        } catch (ce: CancellationException) {
            throw ce // Needed for coroutine scope cancellation
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // display error
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you should run API calls explictly with the IO dispatcher. The rest of your code looks really good.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap `manufacturer.postValue(CarsRepository().getAllManufacturers())` with `try catch` block. If you want to tell user about that error, create another LiveData object, e.g. `val error: MutableLiveData<String>` and post error text from `catch` block.